# Get co-ordinates range while using leaflet

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, google-maps-markers

My application is in Angular 5. I am calling an API and get different data along with latitude & longitude. When I fetch these data, I am rendering markers on map based on lats & longs got from API using [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com) I have created [Marker Cluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) to display markers in better way. You can imagine that markers displayed properly and its working.

Now I want to implement filter when I do ZoomIn & ZoomOut

I.e. When I zoomIn / zoomOut in map, it will cover some area right? I want those co-ordinates of covered area. By that range of co-ordinates I will execute API and get filtered results for that area only.

Any help?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Use the `getBounds()` method on your Leaflet `map` object to obtain a `LatLngBounds` which describes the visible area of your map. You can use its values to feed your API query.

```
var bounds = mymap.getBounds()
```

Documentation at http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-methods-for-getting-map-state

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.